# Opencv camera calibration use for world to view port mapping

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am making an application in image processing where I would like to map the view port coordinates to world window co ordinates I am using python and has obtain transformation rotation matrices and distortion coefficients in opencv cpp documentation it is written that camera callibration can be use for this purpose but I can't able to find how any one can help?

Answer (score 0):

for camera calibration, you have to print chess sheet first from this link : [chess for print](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ojsrodrwzjlwzfp/Chess%20for%20printing.pdf?dl=0)
then use these codes for calibration as follows:

1) Take different position of chess sheet in front of camera, this code open camera and detect chess sheet. After several detection of chess sheet, this calculates coefficients matrix to undistortion of camera image.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

objp = np.zeros((6 * 7, 3), np.float32)
objp[ : , : 2] = np.mgrid[0 : 7, 0 : 6].T.reshape(-1, 2)
objpoints = []
imgpoints = []

criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
(w, h) = (int(cam.get(4)), int(cam.get(3)))

while(True):
    _ , frame = cam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (7, 6), None)

    if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)
        corners = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners)

        cv2.drawChessboardCorners(frame, (7, 6), corners, ret)
        cv2.imshow('Find Chessboard', frame)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.imshow('Find Chessboard', frame)
    print "Number of chess boards find:", len(imgpoints)        
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break

ret, oldMtx, coef, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints,
                                                      gray.shape[: : -1], None, None)
newMtx, roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(oldMtx, coef, (w, h), 1, (w, h))

print "Original Camera Matrix:\n", oldMtx
print "Optimal Camera Matrix:\n", newMtx

np.save("Original camera matrix", oldMtx)
np.save("Distortion coefficients", coef)
np.save("Optimal camera matrix", newMtx)

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

2) Then load matrices and apply `undistort` function to correct camera images with below sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

oldMtx = np.load("Original camera matrix.npy")
coef = np.load("Distortion coefficients.npy")
newMtx = np.load("Optimal camera matrix.npy")

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
(w, h) = (int(cam.get(4)), int(cam.get(3)))

while(True):
    _ , frame = cam.read()

    undis = cv2.undistort(frame, oldMtx, coef, newMtx)

    cv2.imshow("Original vs Undistortion", np.hstack([frame, undis]))
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

these codes work for me. good luck